# how to calculate total Sum in Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel-formula

I am producing last report for my venture. I need to ascertain the Sum of aggregate cells in my excel sheet. I have done the accompanying code. Be that as it may, its not computing the qualities.. Here is my code:

```
        Worksheet.Cells[20, 16].Formula =
                  "Sum(" + Worksheet.Cells[6, 16].Value + 
                 ":" + Worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 16].Value + ")";
```

I need to figure the Cell No 16's Sum esteem and I will show it into Cells[20,16]. Its not working. Anybody help me to settle this?

Comment: What are you seeing? You say "is not showing properly" but you don't say what you are seeing or what you are expecting to see. It might help highlight the issue is you expanded on that. :-)

Comment: Not working.. Im not getting sum values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the two occurrences of `.Value` in your code to `.Address`.

**Update**
... and add a `=` before the `Sum`:

```
Worksheet.Cells[20, 16].Formula =
        "=Sum(" + Worksheet.Cells[6, 16].Address + 
        ":" + Worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 16].Address + ")";
```

Comment: Yes sorry. I forgot the '=' what makes the formula to a formula.

Comment: Hmm... better than nothing :-) Sure that there are values in for example cell P6??

Comment: its working now.. I wasnt convert the Datatype of my Excel column. Previously it was accepting string only. I modified that when i assign,  "Worksheet.Cells[20, 16].Value = Helper.GetInt(location.Qty);"